# urlencode with only built-in functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, urlencode

Without using plpgsql, I'm trying to urlencode a given text within a pgsql SELECT statement.

The problem with this approach:

```
select regexp_replace('héllo there','([^A-Za-z0-9])','%' || encode(E'\\1','hex'),'g')
```

...is that the encode function is not passed the regexp parameter, unless there's another way to call functions from within the replacement expression that actually works.  So I'm wondering if there's a replacement expression that, by itself, can encode matches into hex values.

There may be other combinations of functions.  I thought there would be a clever regex (and that may still be the answer) out there, but I'm having trouble finding it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select regexp_replace(encode('héllo there','hex'),'(..)',E'%\\1','g');
```

This doesn't leave the alphanumeric characters human-readable, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is pretty short version, and it's even "pure SQL" function, not plpgsql. Multibyte chars (including 3- and 4-bytes emoji) are supported.

```
create or replace function urlencode(in_str text, OUT _result text) returns text as $$
  select
    string_agg(
      case
        when ol>1 or ch !~ '[0-9a-za-z:/@._?#-]+' 
          then regexp_replace(upper(substring(ch::bytea::text, 3)), '(..)', E'%\\1', 'g')
        else ch
      end,
      ''
    )
  from (
    select ch, octet_length(ch) as ol
    from regexp_split_to_table($1, '') as ch
  ) as s;
$$ language sql immutable strict;
```

Comment: Note that the `ch::bytea::text` depends on `ch` being parseable as a BYTEA literal.  Which seems to work for everything but `\`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function I wrote that handles encoding using built in functions while preserving the readability of the URL.

Regex matches to capture pairs of (optional) safe characters and (at most one) non-safe character.  Nested selects allow those pairs to be encoded and re-combined returning a fully encoded string.

I've run through a test suite with all sorts of permutations (leading/trailing/only/repeated encoded characters and thus far it seems to encode correctly.

The safe special characters are _ ~ . - and /.  My inclusion of "/" on that list is probably non-standard, but fits the use case I have where the input text may be a path and I want that to remain.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION oseberg.encode_uri(input text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  IMMUTABLE STRICT
AS $function$
DECLARE
  parsed text;
  safePattern text;
BEGIN
  safePattern = 'a-zA-Z0-9_~/\-\.';
  IF input ~ ('[^' || safePattern || ']') THEN
    SELECT STRING_AGG(fragment, '')
    INTO parsed
    FROM (
      SELECT prefix || encoded AS fragment
      FROM (
        SELECT COALESCE(match[1], '') AS prefix,
               COALESCE('%' || encode(match[2]::bytea, 'hex'), '') AS encoded
        FROM (
          SELECT regexp_matches(
            input,
            '([' || safePattern || ']*)([^' || safePattern || '])?',
            'g') AS match
        ) matches
      ) parsed
    ) fragments;
    RETURN parsed;
  ELSE
    RETURN input;
  END IF;
END;
$function$
```

Comment: Thanks for all the time you put into this, but as stated in the OP, I was looking for pure built-in functions, without pl/pgsql.

Comment: There are some problems with multibyte character such as Chinese. 
Beijing (北京市) returns '%e58c97%e4baac%e5b882', it should be '%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC%E5%B8%82'

Answer (score -3):

You can use CLR and import the namespace or use the function shown in this link , this creates a T-SQL function that does the encoding.

http://www.sqljunkies.com/WebLog/peter_debetta/archive/2007/03/09/28987.aspx

Comment: Also, I'm trying to use built-in only, i.e., I don't want to create a function or stored procedure.