# decodeURIComponent for postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, encoding

I use decodeURIComponent and encodeURIComponent in Javascript.
Before I store this data in a UTF-8-PostgreSQL-Database, I should decode them:

[$my_data = pg_escape_string(utf8_encode($_POST['my_data']));](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php)

I'm looking for a PostgreSQL-Function to convert Javascript-Encoded Data.

Comment: This is as useful as storing binaries in the DB as base64-encoded TEXT instead of using BYTEA. Probably sometimes it has is uses but generally? Are you sure you need to do this?

Comment: milen, storing base64 is likely to reduce bandwidth required for storage/retrieval ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You're not making yourself too clear, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341074/urlencode-with-only-built-in-functions) will be of interest for you.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm missing a more complex function:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp

Comment: Well, there's no encodeURI function in postgresql. Maybe, there's one available as module. But I doubt you really need it. What are you trying to achieve?